# Tableview's first column taking a lot of space in javafx 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am using tableview in javafx and the first column is taking a lot of space. Sometimes tableview columns works normally and sometimes it doesn't. I am dynamically making columns and adding to tableview. I am using constrained-resize policy.

JDK 1.8 is used. JavaFx 8 is used. The UI is FXML based.

Below is the example code that can be used to generate the problem. **Please note that sometimes the column width are as expected and sometime first column takes a lot of space. Same behaviour is not everytime with the same code.** The minimum 3 files needed with minimum code for fxml based app is

Main Class

```
public class StackOverFlowQuestion extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
    Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
    stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
    stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Controller Class

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView tableview;
private ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    buildData();
}


public void buildData() {
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    /**
     * ********************************
     * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY * ********************************
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
        final int j = i;
        TableColumn col = new TableColumn("Column No." + i);
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());

            }
        });

        tableview.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);

    }

    /**
     * ******************************
     * Data added to ObservableList * ******************************
     */
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        //Iterate Row
        ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            //Iterate Column
              row.add("Long Data to exceed width " + j + " " + i);
        }
        data.add(row);

    }

    tableview.setItems(data);
    //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView


}
}
```

FXML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1300.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" fx:controller="stackoverflowquestion.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="341.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="1300.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="tableview" prefHeight="200.0" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Below is the actual image from project.**

[image: tableview image]

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem, please?

Comment: @Slaw I have added 3 files with minimum code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: _I have added 3 files_ actually, you didn't - they must be _here_ not at any external location (which tend to wither away ..) The idea of SO is (at least used to be, nowadays I'm not that sure ;) to build a knowledge base for all. Helping a single developer is only part of the game, the more important is to gather questions and answers that might be useful to future readers. The mimium requirement for a question is to be complete and describe a reproducible behaviour. Which it can't with code dropped anywhere else :)

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry, i have added code in stackoverflow and also described the problem more clearly.

Comment: thanks :) don't see anything obviously wrong, and hard to debug when the issue is spurious .. in your shoes as a first step to understand what might go wrong, I would remove all hard-coded sizes (including the forced window sizing) from the ui, just let the defaults rule.